# Can we differentiate a function w.r.t itself?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, chain-rule

A question came to my mind which is: is it possible to differentiate a function with respect to itself?

I tried to think of how it will work and came to this.

I begin with \begin{gather} f(x)=f(x). \end{gather}

It's kind of silly but bear with me.

Then I've applied the definition

\begin{gather}\lim_{f(x) \to f(a)} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)-f(a)}=\lim_{f(x) \to f(a)} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)-f(a)}\end{gather}

the L.H.S will be equal to $1$. Then,

\begin{gather}1=\lim_{f(x) \to f(a)} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)-f(a)}.\end{gather}

The trick I've made is: as ${f(x) \to f(a)} \equiv x\to a$.

Then I rewrote the expression \begin{gather} \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)-(a)} =\lim_{f(x) \to f(a)} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)-f(a)},\end{gather}

I multiplied by $x-a$ up and down,

\begin{gather} \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.\frac{x-a}{f(x)-f(a)},\end{gather}

and I end up with this \begin{gather} 1=f'(a) \frac{dx}{df(x)}.\end{gather}

My question is: is it meaningful to have $\frac{dx}{df(x)}$? The independent variable is $x$, so how could we say that we measure the change of $x$ w.r.t. $f(x)$?

My second question: is it possible to apply the chain rule from the beginning? because I know that we can apply chain rule for a function of some variable, like $f(x)$ for example. But could we apply the chain rule for an independent variable of this function, like $x$ is the independent variable of $f(x)$. Could we say from the beginning $1=f'(x)\frac{dx}{d(f(x))}$, and why?

Comment: I went through your post and tried to fix small grammar mistakes and overall prim it up. Please go through it now that I edited it and make any changes you see fit if my updates changed the intended meaning at all. I did my best to stick to your voice, so hopefully it's only an improvement to the readability, and I didn't change the intended meaning at all.

Comment: I have thought of this thing before and really I've never thought of doing something like this. Since my intuition is to just do the following
$$
\frac{d}{df(x)}x = \frac{d}{df(x)} \left(f^{-1} \circ f\right)(x) = \frac{d}{du} f^{-1}(u) \Bigg|_{u=f(x)}
$$

Comment: You have very nearly discovered (and given a good heuristic for) the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).  If $y = f(x)$, then $x = f^{-1}(y)$.   Then, using your notation $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d} f(x)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{ \mathrm{d} f^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm{dy}}. $$  This is only a hop, skip, and a jump away from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @XanderHenderson                                                                 But is $dx/df(x)$
 valid in the sense that we don't think of$x$ as inverse of another function?

Comment: @Abdelrahman Without more formal definitions, $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}f(x)$ is almost certainly nonsense.  It is an abuse of notation, similar to the abuse of notation which is often used to justify the chain rule.  However, there is a reasonable way of defining that notation, and once you go through that process, the end result is, basically, the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @XanderHenderson , so $dx/df(x)$ has no meaning except in sense we think of $x=g(y)$ ,such that $g$ is the inverse of $f$ ,, but in sense that $y=f(x)$ with no mentioning that $x$ has an inverse of $f$ , it's non sense?

Comment: @Abdelrahman No mathematical symbol has meaning until we *give* it meaning.  The notation you have provided must be given some meaning---a very reasonable meaning, based on the argument you presented, is related to the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @XanderHenderson ,, Why this symbol ($dx/df(x)$) didn't have a meaning in other sense than the inverse function? Like  why we didn't think of it as the charge of $x$ w.r.t $f(x)$ in sense that $y=f(x)$ with no mentioning the inverse function?

Comment: $da/db$, thinking in very fuzzy and general terms,  measures how quickly $a$ changes when $b$ changes. In order for $dx/df$ to make any sense, we have to have some way of determining what change in $x$ results from a change in $f$, i.e. exactly what an inverse of $f$ does. You could try to formulate it without using the word "inverse", but you're going to be using it at least implicitly, and no one has ever shown there to be any advantage from avoiding it.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, the collection of symbols
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
is not a fraction—it is not the ratio of two real numbers, for example.  There are many different ways of explaining *precisely* what this notation means (e.g. as a fraction of hyperreal numbers, in the sense of Abraham's nonstandard analysis; or as the result of an operator acting on the function $f$; or a bunch of other things), and there are many abuses of this notation which give good heuristics for true results (such as the chain rule).  However, at the level of introductory calculus, this object should be treated as a single symbol, which represents the evaluation of the derivative function at a specific point.

What this means is that the step in the question
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{x-a}{f(x) - f(a)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f(x)} $$
is, essentially, nonsense.  It doesn't really mean anything in terms of the way in which these symbols are typically defined.

That being said, it is possible to give a reasonable meaning to this notation via the chain rule:  if $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable functions, then, via a very slight abuse of notation,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(f\circ g)(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} f( g(x) )}{\mathrm{d}g(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}. $$
Thus, in the context of the chain rule, it can make sense to write something like
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f(x)}. $$
However, note that I am thinking of this in the same way that I think about the notation used for the chain rule:  to write
$ {\mathrm{d}g}/{\mathrm{d}f}$
(where $f$ and $g$ are functions) is to implicitly assume that $g$ is a function of $f$.

Therefore, if I write
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f(x)}, $$
I am implicitly assuming that $x$ is a function of $f(x)$, i.e. there exists some differentiable function $g$ so that $x = g(f(x))$.  But the functional equation $x = g(f(x))$ has a solution!  By definition,
$$ x = g(f(x)) \implies g = f^{-1}. $$
In other words, *if* the notation $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}f(x)$ is going to have any meaning, *then* it almost certainly must mean the same thing as
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f^{-1}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}f(x)}. $$
But *this* notation has a very reasonable meaning in terms of the chain rule:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(f^{-1}\circ f)(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}f^{-1}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}f(x)}}_{=\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}f(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
= (f^{-1})'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x).
$$
As such, it would appear that *if* the notation $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}f(x)$ is sensible notation, then the only thing it can reasonably mean is "the derivative of the inverse of $f$, with respect to its argument, $f(x)$".

Finally, it is argued in the original question that it should be the case that
$$ 1
= \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
=(f^{-1})'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)
\implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{(f^{-1})'(f(x))},  $$
which is basically a restatement of the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).  As such, we have stumbled into a *really good* heuristic argument for the Inverse Function Theorem.  This isn't quite a proof (there are some assumptions and hypotheses which would need to be cleaned up a bit, and the argument doesn't *completely* hold water; but these problems can be fixed), but the overall argument is fairly convincing.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dx}{d(f(x))}$ is completely valid if $x$ can be expressed as a function of $f(x)$, i.e., $x=g(f(x))$.

This function $g$ is the inverse of the function $f$, i.e. $f^{-1}$, hence the function $f$ must be invertible.

$g(x)$ must also be a differentiable function with respect to $x$.

Comment: But is $dx/df(x)$ valid in the sense that we don't think of $x$ as inverse of another function?

Comment: You don't need to think of $x$ in terms of the inverse function, I'm just saying that such an inverse function must exist; otherwise $x$ might become multi-valued, hence non-differentiable.

Comment: ,, so we could have $dx/df(x)$ ,, even if we didn't think of $x$ as an inverse of another function?